# How do I send a packet in AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

I'd like to send a some packet to modbus/tcp device to control it.
I do success in python as follow:

```
sdata = struct.pack('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x09,0x01,0x10,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x00,0x01)
sock.send(sdata)
```

And it works well;

But now I don't know how to do like this in Autoit.

I try to do like this:

```
$szData = Binary("0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x09,0x01,0x10,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x00,0x01");
TCPSend($ConnectedSocket, $szData)
```

But this does not work like above python source.

Comment: What is the value of @error after TCPSend()?  Here is a list of Windows Socket Error codes:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

AutoIt is not Python. The AutoIt Binary function does not work the same as struct.pack in Python. AutoIt expects input like this:

```
$szData = Binary("0x000000000009011000080001020001")
```

If you still want to input your data like this: "0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00" then you will have to invent your own Binary function. A simple "hack" is:

```
Func _Binary($s)
   $b = StringReplace($s, ",0x", "") ; Replaces ,0x with empty string
   Return Binary($b)
EndFunc
```